# Printing data using JavaScript taken from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to learn how to debug jquery. I tried to make a page which will dynamically add input feilds. The data is sent to the jquery. Now for debugging, I tried to `console.log` the whole array, but I am getting this error in Firefox:

> [17:40:27.073] The character encoding of the HTML document was not
>   declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser
>   configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
>   US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in
>   the document or in the transfer protocol. @
>   file:///Users/ateevchopra/Desktop/takemehome%20dynamic/TakeMeHome/index.html

Please explain what this means of if there is some mistake in my code. Heres my code

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

 <head>
    <title>TakeMeHome</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/app.js'></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <center><form id="details">
      Your Place:<input id="source" type="text"><br><br>
      Friend1:<input id="friend1" type="text"><br><br>
      <div id="friends"></div>
      <div id="button">Add!</div><br><br>

       <input type="submit" value="go">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 var j=2;
var friends = [];


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(){
      if(j<11){
          $('#friends').append('Friend'+j+':<input type="text" id="friend'+j+'"/><br/><br/>'); 
        j++;
      }
     else
      {
     alert("Limit reached");
   }
    });



});


$("form").submit(function(){

    friends[0] = ('#source').val();
    for(var i=1;i<j;i++)
    {
        friends[i] = ('#friends'+i+'').val();
    }

    console.log(friends);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working perfectly you can see it from [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/fqQLC/)
console.log is good for debuging but i prefer you to use firebug for debuging.
Using firebug you can debug each and every line and you can also view the values of each variable.
I am using firebug with firefox.
You can download firebug for firefox from that [link](https://www.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) .I hope that it helps you.

Comment: hey i am looking at the jsfiddle. the alert i get says "fired" every time. But it should show the  list of friends that i enter. Why isnt that coming ?

Comment: i updated the fiddle now it will provide you the friends in var f. I also did some changes in <html> too. now it will provide you all the text boxes and you can get the value form each text box..[jsfile](http://www.jsfiddle.net/fqQLC/1/)

Comment: still i am not getting the list !

Comment: in alert you see the number of controls  and it is providing you correct count. f is the number of friends text boxes

Comment: i dont want the number of friends, i want all my inputs to be displayed. Now when i change the line 19 in js to  console.log(f);it just shows me object,object. But i want what i entred. are you getting ?

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with JavaSCript.

If you add a meta tag like `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` it should be fixed.

I also see the you have a type in doctype  declaration.

Comment: but whenever i try this in my browser, i am not getting an alert with all the friends name i entered. ?

Comment: that is because you have errors in your js, One of the error is see is that you have multiple jquery files included. Including different versions of jquery on same page may cause conflicts.

Comment: which one should i remove ?

Comment: any one, but that doesn't mean it will fix. there can be other issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error in your Javascript code, but a general warning issued by Firefox regarding the validity of the actual HTML markup.

The document's encoding should be declared with a `meta` tag in inside the `header` tag. For example, if your encoding is UTF-8 it would be:

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    ...
</head>
```

Since your doctype is HTML5, you can also use the `charset` attribute:

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ...
</head>
```